# Creating an iterator and choose among several sources of iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, redefinition

I want to create an Iterator that would have several "sources" of objects to iterate. I would like to be able to give its `__next__()` method an optional keyword argument that would offer the possibility to choose the source (no keyword argument would mean, just choose a source randomly).

Using `__next__()` causes problems (see below), so as a workaround I've written this unsatisfying code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

class infinite_iterator(object):

    def __init__(self, sources):
        self.collector = []
        for s in sources:
            random.shuffle(s)
            self.collector.append([])
        self.sources = sources

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    # Workaround: calling it next instead of __next__
    # (not the python3 way...)
    def next(self, **kwargs):
        sce_nb = random.choice([ n for n in range(len(self.sources)) ])
        if 'choice' in kwargs:
            sce_nb = kwargs['choice']
        self.collector[sce_nb].append(self.sources[sce_nb][0])
        output = self.sources[sce_nb].pop(0)
        # Repopulate any empty 'source'
        if not self.sources[sce_nb]:
            (self.sources[sce_nb], self.collector[sce_nb]) = \
                         (self.collector[sce_nb], self.sources[sce_nb])
            random.shuffle(self.sources[sce_nb])
        return output


S = infinite_iterator([["Adam", "Paul", "Oliver", "Aaron", "Joshua", "Jack"],
                       ["Mary", "Sophia", "Emily", "Isobel", "Grace", "Alice", "Lucy"]])

print("Any name: " + S.next())
print("Any girl's name: " + S.next(choice=1))
print("Any boy's name: " + S.next(choice=0))
```

Problem is, if I want to write `def __next__(self, **kwargs):` to make infinite_iterator a real Iterator, then of course I want to write:

```
print("Any name: " + next(S))
print("Any girl's name: " + next(S, choice=1))
print("Any boy's name: " + next(S, choice=0))
```

but get an error (2d line):

```
TypeError: next() takes no keyword arguments
```

I thought this call `next(S, choice=1)` would use the `__next__()` function defined in the object. Because of this error, I think that on one hand it actually does not. This could be expectable because it's not exactly a redefinition, as infinite_iterator does not inherit from an "Iterator object" (as far as I understand, there's no such object). But on another hand, if I call only `next(S)` it works, and in this case, *my* `__next__()` method is really called (it chooses randomly a list to iterate over).

Finally, is there a solution to realize such an Iterator?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to pass arguments to `__next__`? The protocol clearly defined that this hook takes no arguments.

Comment: `next` uses `__next__` but it is not the same thing. `__next__` is a *hook*.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) (technically a coroutine) and use `send` to pass in your choices:

```
import random
def selector(sources):
    option = None
    while True:
        if option is None:
            option = yield random.choice(random.choice(sources))
        else:
            option = yield random.choice(sources[option])

s = selector([["Adam", "Paul", "Oliver", "Aaron", "Joshua", "Jack"],
              ["Mary", "Sophia", "Emily", "Isobel", "Grace", "Alice", "Lucy"]])

print("Any name: " + next(s))
print("Any girl's name: " + s.send(1))
print("Any boy's name: " + s.send(0))
```

The way this works is every time you call `send`, that value gets passed in to the `option` variable which is used to make the selection for the next iteration of the while loop.

You'll have to start it up by calling `next` at least once so it hits the first `yield` statement, but after that it'll work both ways (use `next` or `send(None)` for a full random choice, or `send(option)` for a specific source.

Comment: OK, so it's impossible to use `__next__` calling it this way: `next(s, choice=1)`?

Comment: That's not how the iterator protocol (or the `next` builtin) is defined, and you can't change that definition, so no. But `send` works, I'm not sure why you're stuck on using `next` in particular.